# Looping over tags/aliases instead of whole resource

Tags: terraform, datadog

I'm trying to figure out a way to loop over a list of aliases for Datadog dashboards.
In 1 single dashboard I want to have multiple servers involved that will be fetched from variables.

For example:

```
variable "africa" {
  type = map(any)
  default = {
    "server1" = {
      alias              = "server1"
      hostname           = "hostname1"
      name               = "query1"
      formula_expression = "query1 * 8"
    }
    "server2" = {
      name               = "server2"
      hostname           = "hostname2"
      name               = "query2"
      formula_expression = "query2 * 8"
    }
    "server3" = {
      name               = "server3
      hostname           = "hostname3"
      name               = "query3"
      formula_expression = "query3 * 8"
    }
  }
}
```

```
resource "datadog_dashboard" "global_dashboards_africa" {

  title       = "Terraform - Africa"
  description = "Dashboards for Global"
  layout_type = "ordered"
  widget {
    group_definition {
      title       = "Quick Overview"
      show_title  = "true"
      layout_type = "ordered"
      widget {
        timeseries_definition {
          title          = "Traffic"
          title_size     = "16"
          title_align    = "left"
          show_legend    = false
          legend_layout  = "auto"
          legend_columns = ["avg", "min", "max", "value", "sum"]
          request {
            for server in var.africa:
            formula {
              alias              = ${alias}
              formula_expression = ${formula_expression}
            }
            query {
              metric_query {
                name  = ${name}
                query = "max:system.net.bytes_sent{device:bond0,host:${hostname}}"
              }
            }
            style {
              palette    = "warm"
              line_type  = "solid"
              line_width = "normal"
            }
            display_type = "area"
          }
          yaxis {
            include_zero = "true"
            scale        = "linear"
            min          = "auto"
            max          = "auto"
          }
        }
        widget_layout {
          x      = "0"
          y      = "5"
          width  = "12"
          height = "5"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've added for_each at the top, right after resource but it creates only 3 resources. I want to create 1 resource and in aliases - add like 50 servers with hostnames and names in specific locations.
I've tried multiple solutions but Terraform cannot help me with this.

Comment: Please add the entire resource code block to the question.

Comment: I didn't use Data Dog, nor their provider, but I think that you might be looking for something like [dynamic blocks](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks) please attach a minimal example of your resource block and what do you want to achieve exactly

Comment: Added entire resource block.

What I want to achieve is actually creating 1 resource [dashboard] and in that dashboard have 1 formula block matching 1 query block for EVERY server included in variable africa.